# How to set add_query_arg properly for home page?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I want to add `lang` query variable to existing URL.

I have registered query variable:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_add_query_vars');
function custom_add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "lang";
    return $vars;
}
```

The following code works good everywhere but not when I'm currently on the home page.

```
<?php global $wp; ?>
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array('lang' => 'en'), $wp->request); ?>">English</a>
```

Is there a problem with the code? On the homepage
URL becomes `http://localhost/mywebsitename/?lang=en` which should be ok but supposedly it tries to load `index.php` instead of `page.php`, which generally wouldn't be a problem but in that case some things like `is_front_page()` don't behave as it should.

Static page is set as a homepage under Settings->Reading and pretty permalinks are active ("Post name" option).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a problem with the code?

Your code is already properly adding the `lang` query variable to the homepage URL. But you need to understand these points:

1. > On the homepage URL becomes `http://localhost/mywebsitename/?lang=en` which should be ok

   `$wp->request` is empty on the homepage, hence the above URL is expected. And you could use `get_queried_object()->post_name` to force the Page's slug be in that URL, but WordPress would actually redirect you to the URL without that slug, because the Page is set as the static front page, which means the content at `example.com` and `example.com/page-slug/` are identical and thus WordPress performs a (canonical) redirect when loading the latter URL.
2. > but supposedly it tries to load `index.php` instead of `page.php`, which generally wouldn't be a problem but in that case some things like `is_front_page()` don't behave as it should

   No, WordPress will try to [load `front-page.php`, `home.php` or `page.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display) before falling back to the index template. But even if the index template is used, `is_front_page()` would still behave properly — remember that the query determines the template and not the other way round.

   So one could say that "if `is_front_page()` returns true, `page.php` might be used", but this is incorrect: "if `index.php` is used, `is_front_page()` would return false".